# Why I cannot add or install anything to my terminal in VS code after I save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new with VS code. I am working with react and whenever I make some changes I cannot add any code or install anything to my terminal. I need to initialize firebase. I know the solution might be simple but I am new with VS code and I cannot find anything related to this issue in the VS code documentation. Here is an image of the terminal which shows that I cannot type in anything in the terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enc0n.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  So others can help you more easily, [please post your output as text, not an image of your output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the capture, I guess you started the server from that terminal. While the server is running, the terminal does not accept input from keyboard. (And this will not be specific to VSCode's terminal)

If you press `ctrl + C` you can stop the server then your terminal will show prompt and accept input.

Comment: Thank so much that actually worked!